# Fixing ERROR: cluster setting 'kv.rangefeed.enabled' is currently overridden by the operator in CockroachDB Serverless

Tags: cockroachdb

I'm following a guide for setting up a changefeed on CockroachDB, but right from the start I get the error `cluster setting 'kv.rangefeed.enabled' is currently overridden by the operator`. How can I enable changefeeds?

Answer (score 1):

In CockroachDB Serverless, it's not necessary to set `kv.rangefeed.enabled`--you can just skip that part of the setup. If you're setting up a changefeed to write to external endpoints, you may need to have a credit card on file in your Serverless account, but you can keep your spend limit set to $0 and still run changefeeds.